# Count number of characters of only text of an HTML string and insert in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which contains HTML, for example:

"<html><p style="border:1px solid #000">this is my text<span style="color:red">in red</span></p></html>"

I am trying to add a "<br>" after the 5th character, so that the string becomes:

"<html><p style="border:1px solid #000">this <br>is my text<span style="color:red">in red<span></p></html>"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would advise against using regex for that one, you should probably remove the tag.

Comment: how did u counting the word?

Comment: Also the input example contains less than 5 words, and differs from the output example by more than a `<br>` tag

Comment: Title says "number of character", question says "number of word". Maybe sit back, take a deep breath, and revise this question.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i would like to insert <br> after 5 characters

Comment: You should get the `p` element, then grab the text inside it. Then you can count characters from the beginning of the string.

Comment: grabbing the text will only allow me to insert in the string without the html, how do i do it with the html intact

Comment: regex isn't the greatest for parsing HTML, but you need to have the string with the HTML when all is said and done? And there can be tags in the midst of the displayed text (as your span in the example)?
This can get you started, it will select all the beginning tags, the first 5 chars, then everything else. - (<.*?>)*(.{5}).+
() are capturing groups to keep match, <> for matching beginning and end of a tag, .*? as non-greedy match to get whatever is in a tag (but only for one tag) * to get all the first tags .{5} to get 5 characters...

Comment: Note! my above regex fails for something like <html><p style="border:1px solid #000">is <span class="red">this</span> my text</p></html>
because the span tag is separate from the others.

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, could you mark the answer of your choice as accepted or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a HTML-parser style solution (not regex):

```js
function insertBreak(html, insertAt) {
    // Create document from HTML:
    var doc = document.createElement('div');
    doc.innerHTML = html;
    // Create a walker to visit all text nodes
    var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(doc, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, null);
    // Create BR element that will be inserted
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    var node;
    while (node = nodes.nextNode()) {
        if (insertAt <= node.nodeValue.length) {
            // Found where to insert the BR. Split the text node
            var before = document.createTextNode(node.nodeValue.substr(0, insertAt));
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(br, node);
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(before, br);
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.substr(insertAt);
            break;
        }
        insertAt -= node.nodeValue.length;
    }
    // Restore HTML tags as they get stripped
    return '<html>' + doc.innerHTML + '</html>';
}

// Example data and call
var html = '<html><p style="border:1px solid #000">this is my text<span style="color:red">in red<span></p></html>';
html = insertBreak(html, 5);

console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments - you should probably use a html parser for this. It *can* however be done in regex.

```
(<p[^<>]*>[\w\s]{5})
```

It finds the paragraph tag `p`, and matches up to the closing `>`. Then it matches 5 word characters or spaces.

Replace all with itself **plus** `<br>`

```
$1<br>
```

If it should match any 5 characters you could change the `[\w\s]*` part to simply `.*`.

```js
var str='<html><p style="border:1px solid #000">this is my text<span style="color:red">in red</span></p></html>';
document.write(str.replace(/(<p[^<>]*>[\w\s]{5})/, '$1<br>'));
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mQ7nX3/1).

Comment: what if there are multiple tags encountered in between the number of characters

Comment: Then it *could* fail. That's why I and several others stated - "use a html parser".